# Visual Studio 2013 C# Web Project builds but IDE reports The type or namespace name xxx could not be found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

When opening an MVC4 C# web project in Visual Studio 2013, the IDE reports the error "The type or namespace name '*_*' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)", but the project builds and runs without any errors. Furthermore, intellisense does not include the project namespace.

The "missing" reference is to files within the same project.
for example; the web project namespace is "webproject.com", and references in a controller files to "webproject.com.models" is underlined in red with the error above.

I have checked the following:

- All Solution projects are configured to use the same Target Framework(.Net 4)
- web.config in the Views folder contains the namespace in the system.web.webPages.razor section
- cleaned and rebuilt solution
- deleted all bin and obj content
- deleted .suo and .csproj.user files that were created by VS2010

The only way that I can get rid of these errors being reported in VS2013 is to unload then reload the project.

When opened in Visual Studio 2010 I do not get these problems.

Comment: I think you may need to report this to VS team!

Comment: I have the same problem. Unload, reload project fixes my issue.

Comment: nemke's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 16):

I have the same issue.

ALthough the project compiles correctly, the code editor shows an error The type or namespace name '_' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference).

THere is one workaround. Just delete the *.SUO files and re-open the solution. THen for this only Session it works. Unfortunately after closing and reopening the solution the issue is back again. VS 2012 works fine.

Seems to be a bug in VS 2013....

Comment: I think I may have fixed this issue by taking the following steps:


1) I deleted all content from c:\users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 and  c:\users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0


2) Deleted .suo files


3) In VS Selected Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings


Since performing the steps above I have had no more namespace "errors"

Comment: @simonco Just doing step 1 seems to have worked for me.

Comment: @simonco, the first and second options, along with a "devenv /setup" has solved the issue to me.

Comment: @simonco - until I reboot VisualStudio, that solved my problem

Comment: First comment helped me - problem is gone now.

Answer (score 8):

My solution, when I encountered the problem with VS 2013 Express edition was to simply unload the offending project and reload. Opening the SUO or Project file and making changes had not affect.

Comment: I have had this issue happen a couple times with VS 2013. Unloading and reloading worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Try to unload the project in VS2013, then right click the node and select edit "projectname.csproj". Check the individual references they might point to somewhere strange.

EDIT: the csproj file is an xml file and the references are located under Project -> ItemGroup -> Reference

Comment: All the references are to assemblies located in the ..\packages folder and nothing stands out as incorrect. As stated above, the "namespace cannot be found" message relates to a namespace within the same project as opposed to an external reference.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Helped me - cheers! The IDE said it was reading an assembly from one place but a hint in the project file said to get it from elsewhere...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

It's a VS 2012 solution with different projects.

Search for all *.suo files and deleted them.
Rebuild and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: @Andrei_N I'm having the same problem with projects in TFS, this solution worked for me... until I saved the project and open it again, the problem comes back - VS2013 & TFS2013. Any ideas why it keeps reappearing?

Comment: @harag try this one: http://enginecore.blogspot.ro/2014/01/invalid-markup-in-xaml-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: @Andrei_N Thanks for the link, I've tried what you suggest but still had the same issue, even tried the comment of unloading and reloading the project, which worked... until I closed and reopened the solution.  I posted a question here about it as it only seems to be the version of the solution I have in TFS, the none TFS version works well. I installed TFS Express yesterday and added a project to it.

Comment: in this case since TFS seems to be the culprit, I suggest you contact someone from TFS team or find the TFS forum on MS forums website

Answer (score 2):

There's a known issue with Web Application projects when bound to a TFS server that sounds like this issue. This occurs when the following TFS setting option is checked:

Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Get everything when a solution or project is opened.

Disabling this option resolves the problem.

thanks,
Miguel Lacouture
[MSFT]

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, on project reference.
I opened the referenced project file (*.csproj) with a text editor and did some cleanup:

1) reset these properties' values:

```
<PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
<InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
<UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
<IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
<TargetFrameworkProfile />
```

2) removed dirty platform/configurations:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'x86|AnyCPU'">
...
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'x86|x86'">
...
```

Now I can compile without any issue.
Glad to share it with you! :))

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Opening the project's properties and making a change to the name (or any value) and then rebuilding seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem and none of the solutions here helped. I fixed mine by doing a repair of Visual Studio (An option when you select to uninstall the program). Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I added a new  class file ( e.g. MyClass.cs) and called it in some other C# code places. For some reason VS did not add that new class file to my working project folder (not seen in VS, but seen in Windows File Explorer).  And, hence, the compile path for new class file is not included in the compile section of my project file (e.g. MyProject.csproj).  So to solve this problem, First, right click on your working project > Add > Existing Item ... > Select your new class > OK.

Then, check the project file (*.csproj) and make sure a new element is inserted in the compile section such as:

Finally, rebuild your project and the problem should be solved.

Another reason for this issue is the project, I had long ago with VS, is my other project was set up with Client Profile as its target framework.  So, to solve the issue: Right click your project in VS > Properties > Application tab > make sure Target Framework option is not **Client Profile**.  You should change all projects in your solution to the **same** framework version AND all of them must **not** have Client Profile option.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft just released a new security update to be automatically applied to machines configured to use Microsoft Update.

Unfortunately, some ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4 VS projects can no longer build after the update is applied. These projects will fail with the following error:

"Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Mvc,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,processorArchitecture=MSIL"

My project also had the error "The type or namespace name 'System.Web.Mvc' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)". Installing the latest version of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc solved my problem. See the following article from Microsoft for more info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unloading and then reloading the project worked for me.