# The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'PartyInvites'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, asp.net-mvc-5

Using VS2013 Pro, TFS 2013 Express

I'm currently doing a tutorial from the book asp.net mvc 5 and everything was fine. 
yesterday I installed TFS 2013 Express onto my local machine, copied the project over to the TFS folder and added the project to source control.

Since doing that I'm now getting errors like the subject. In this case the controller simply has a using:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PartyInvites.**Models**;

namespace PartyInvites.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //  return View();
        //}

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewBag.Greeting = hour < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Afternoon";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm(**GuestResponse** guestResponse)
        {
            //todo: Email response to the party organizer
            return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

in the HttpPost, the object "GuestResponse" is where the red line is, but this object IS in the models namespace etc. *EDIT* The red line is also on the word "Models" in the using statement at the top.

Now I've noticed that if I delete the SUO file from the solution folder and open the solution the error goes away, but as soon as I save the solution and reopen it the error comes back. I've also notice this same problem is a couple of other projects I know work.

Also - When I build the solutions they build with no errors, but the red lines are still there.

I think the problem is with the SUO file and TFS as the solution works absolutely fine in the None TFS version, but I can't find a solution to SUO and TFS. I am the sole user of the PC and have full admin rights.

Q) Does anyone know how to solve this problem so I don't have to delete the SUO file all the time?

**EDIT 1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PartyInvites.Models
{
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've now tried to FILE>SourceControl>Change source control to Unbind from source control, and it's now working as expected... but it's now not in source control. I think this issue is now down to TFS related. -- Update. After rebinding it back to TFS, the problem returns.

Comment: what happens if you fully qualify the class name?  maybe there is a namespace collision

Comment: No there is no namespace collision, the project builds fine. the red line is also on the "using PartyInvites.Models;" on "Models" at the top. it's very strange.

Comment: Can you post the class including the namespace declaration for GuestResponse. This will help us verify the namespace. You can also try 'Clean Solution' and then 'Rebuild Solution' but without the class contents not much we can do to help :/

Comment: @Tony I've edited the question and added in the GuestResponse class. As you can see the namespace etc. is fine. The actual project compiles & runs with no errors, and the problem goes away the first time I load the project after deleting the SUO file (or unload/reload project). Yep, also tried clean / rebuild as well.

Comment: I would be interested to know if you rename PartyInvites.Models to PartyInvites.MyModels and update the using statement then rebuild, if this would be a bandage. Not sure why the SUO would be maken a difference here as it is not a solution option -shrug.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for the suggestion, didn't think of that one. Tried it - No luck - "using PartyInvites.MyModels;" I get the red line on MyModels now (as well as the GuestResponse object), again the solution builds/runs fine. Also if I delete the SUO it appears fine first time around as well.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party plugins or apps? This is a strange issue indeed. Are you running VS as an administrator?

Comment: Just found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422007/visual-studio-2013-c-sharp-web-project-builds-but-ide-reports-the-type-or-namesp  one user said they change the project name in the project properties and rebuilt and it fixed it, another cleaned up the project file itself which is kinda what I was thinking an extra reference or misconfigured.

Comment: @Tony Yes I've got 3rd party plugins, and disabled all that I could but same result. Yes running VS as admin as well. I'll try that other post you linked to. thanks

Comment: @harag, good luck sorry i was not of more help, that post sounds like a lot of desperate people. it would suck to have an established project 3yrs deep and start running into that issue yikes.

Comment: @Tony I found that post you linked to as well, that one gave me the idea to delete the SUO file. Luckily I've only moved a couple of projects into TFS recently. As mentioned before, the exact same MVC project above works fine when I use the none TFS version. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Tony I've now tried to FILE>SourceControl>Unbind from source control, and it's now working as expected... but it's now not in source control. I think this issue is now down to TFS related. -- Update. After rebinding it back to TFS, the problem returns. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update, yeah i was thinking about that after you mentioned you added it to TFS and it started happening. That stinks :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found an answer that worked. It's a bug in VS2013 that is causing the problem, below is the link with the answer.

but in short, turning off the "Get everything when a solution or project is open" solves the problem, though not a complete fix, but for me it solved the problem

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760443/visual-studio-2012-ide-loses-intellisense-and-reference-resolution

Hope this helps others.

Comment: The link is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and i solved it by noticing that my newly added model name was e.g **abc.Models** while my application name was **xyz** and all other models lie in **xyz** namespace  so i edited the trouble making model and changed its namespace to **xyz.Models** and that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

My Models namespace for me was trying to run under APPNameSpace.APPNameSpace.Models Enable-Migrations built the classes as APPNameSpace.Models so I removed the APPNameSpace from the start of each class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same in a .Net Core 3.1 project. For me it was a bad import in my _viewimports.cshtml:

```
@using MyProject.Domain.Model
@using MyProject.Domain.Common /* -- My bad namespace here -- */
@using MyProject.Web.Configuration
@using MyProject.Web.Areas.Shared.Utils
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Because I moved the model folder to the newly created class library project.  When I check the viewimport file, there was old path of model folder. I updated the path, then it is solved.