# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate breaking dependencies every code edit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am not sure why this is happening but no matter the app (even brand new ones) I get a multitude of errors stating that referenced assemblies/namespaces could not be found. The project still runs if I build it and if I clean it all the errors go away until I edit the code again. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

My packages seem to look fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

And here is my web.config

```
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Some things I have tried

- Checking each project to make sure it references .net 4.5
- Deleting the .suo file and restarting visual studio
- Cleaning the whole solution and rebuilding
- Restarting visual studio without doing any of the above

Each of these works temporarily but as soon as I change tabs in VS or edit a line of code problems come back. I am now even having issues with intellisense not popping up either.

Comment: Sounds like a project problem. Where did it come from? Has it been upgraded? What if you create a new project? So many questions...

Comment: I created it from scratch and selected the MVC radio button when I first made it. I then used nuget to update EF 6.0 to 6.1. Now that I think about it, it makes a bit of sense why all the Identity stuff is bugging out.

Comment: So is this still a live question?

Comment: At the moment yes. I think the problem was I had an EF 6 project in my solution and had changed the default identity entity framework references when I used nuget. I started the project over to try and confirm.

Comment: @david.pfx it appears to be a bug in VS 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. It appears to be a bug in Visual Studio 2013 that gets triggered if you have "Get everything when a solution or project is open" under Tools>Options>Source Control>Environment. Deselect that and everything will be okay.

Reference
[The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'PartyInvites'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969571/the-type-or-namespace-name-models-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-partyinvite)