# Recurring namespace errors, but project compiles

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've been having a recurring namespace error inside one of my projects. All the references that are having issues are inside the same project and appear to be properly namespaced. Clearing some VS cache files appears to fix the problem temporarily (AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 and AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0). This isn't a show-stopper by any means; it just means I can't use intellisense or code navigation.

This is especially annoying because I have two files in the same folder referencing the same namespace, with the code content in those files namespaced identically, but VS cannot find the namespace I want in one file but it can in the other. E.g....

```
using System;
using ExampleNamespace.Model;

namespace ExampleNamespace.DAL{
    ..... code content .....
}
```

Is the same from one file to the other. The only difference is in one file, it cannot find ExampleNamespace.Model and all the types in the namespace are not valid.

Other things I've tried:

- Resetting the target framework
- Build Action on files is set to compile
- Deleting cache files (as above)
- Opening/closing VS

I've searched high and low for an answer, but haven't found one. My main question is why the project compiles at all if the IDE can't find a reference? Doesn't the IDE essentially pseudo-compile the code to do intellisense/syntax and bug high-lighting?

Comment: Missing semicolon after your second `using` statement?

Comment: Are the two files part of a single project P1, or is one of them also used as a reference in another project P2? Could be that P2 is missing some dependency. For example, ExampleNamespace.Model
is in assembly A, P1 references assembly A in _\bin\Release_ but P2 references assembly A in _\bin\Debug_. Or something like it.

Comment: @groverboy The files are in a single project.

Comment: @knittl Haha, good catch, but that's not the problem in the source code, obviously.

Comment: Smells like a bug in VS, but try the suggested [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422007/visual-studio-2013-c-sharp-web-project-builds-but-ide-reports-the-type-or-namesp). I've had good (unrelated) results cleaning up the .csproj file.