# type or namespace name could not be found, for all namespaces in MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, suo

We are in the process of upgrading our MVC3 site to MVC4 plus converting all the .aspx views to Razor .cshtml. Project still targets the .NET Framework 4 (I'm trying to tackle one big change at a time here).

Right now the web app project in Visual Studio 2013 gives the same error hundreds of times all over the place

> *The type or namespace name 'My_MVC4_Site' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

or it complains about a namespace under that like My_MVC4_Site.Models. This is the default namespace of the web app itself! So every View's `@model` directive has that error. And even in other codefiles that are part of a Model or Controller, there are 'could not be found' errors, and not only for the project's top-level namespace… like there'll be a definition for an interface or enum in a .cs file, then lower down in the *same* file VS will say that it's not defined.

Weirdest thing of all is that the project still **builds**, and I can run it in Debug from Visual Studio. So it seems that it's just Visual Studio freaking out about something.

But I'd *really* like to fix it so it's not showing me hundreds of "errors" while I'm coding, disabling a lot of basic stuff like F12 Go To Definition, IntelliSense, etc.

- I verified that the Default namespace in the project's properties is correct
- I have put the project's namespace in the Views folder Web.config  section
- I checked the namespace name for typos, of course

None of that made any difference.

**UPDATE**

The solution Configuration Manager and the MVC4 web app project itself builds to the Any CPU platform, the only option available for that project. A couple of the other dependent projects were like that too, but most of the projects included in the solution had Any CPU, x86 and x64 as options. So when the Active solution platform was set to x86 or x64 (the only build options I have ever used), most projects switch accordingly but a couple always stayed at Any CPU.

That was never a problem when this was an MVC3 project in Visual Studio 2010, but I created an x86 platform for the remaining projects, cleared the solution, closed & reopened VS, rebuilt the solution, and *it worked*. All of those "type or namespace…could not be found" errors are gone. VS is acting like an IDE again, I can use View in Page Inspector on my MVC views, and everything.

**UPDATE 2**

That worked for a few days, then the exact problem returned: every View is showing an error in its `@model` that it can't find the namespace, and everything else described above.

The solution configuration has not changed. I can't find anything in the projects or solution that changed since it was working yesterday.

**UPDATE 3**

I got into an old dev box at work that no one had gotten around to reimaging yet, running Visual *Studio 2012 Update 4*. Zipped up my whole MVC4 project and unzipped it there. The only way I modified it was change the project references (since various dependent project in the solution had different paths from there) but otherwise made no changes. The project in VS2012 does not have any of those problems: no erroneous errors, IntelliSense and Page Inspector work perfectly and everything.

So this MVC4 project, which was originally an MVC3 project in VS2010 that was upgraded to MVC4 and then developed a bit in VS2012, just has a problem with VS2013.

**UPDATE 4**

While working on something else, I downloaded & unzipped an MVC3 sample project (https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/MvcRemoteValidationSample in case you're curious) and opened it in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3 or 4 at the time; I'm currently on 4). After going thru the usual automated conversion process (because it was a VS2010 solution), the project exhibited all of the same symptoms. So that confirmed my theory that this has something to do with VS2013 having deprecated support for MVC3. I upped the sample solution from MVC3 to 4 following all the best practices I could find for doing so: no improvement.

**I closed Visual Studio 2013, deleted the .suo file of the solution, re-opened VS2013, and the errors went away.**

I did the same thing for my real web project and the errors also went away. I was actually able to use VS *like a real IDE* on this project for the first time in months!

But like *all* the other workarounds I've found so far, it's only temporary: the namespace errors always come back after a day or two, so I keep having to close, delete the .suo, and reopen.

Comment: Nobody has a theory on this, eh?

Comment: After over a week of spending some time searching for similar issues, I finally found one: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727729/viewbag-not-recognized-in-asp-net-mvc-4-project looks very similar. Supposedly it is an MVC4 bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Found another http://forums.asp.net/t/1857937.aspx?How+to+debug+asp+net+mvc+4+source+code+with+Intellisense+enabled that looks even more like my problem. But the solution there—adding @using statements to all the .cshtml files for all needed namespaces—doesn't help me at all.

Comment: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red Describes exactly the problem I'm having (in far fewer words!) and validates the fix of deleting the .suo file. This is still an open question tho, because WHY do I have to do this almost everyday, sometimes more than once a day, with this particular MVC4 solution?

Comment: Almost identical question as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken – the only step I hadn't tried yet was deleting that folder under AppData.

Comment: Even closer — my question probably should be marked as a dup — is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422007/visual-studio-2013-c-sharp-web-project-builds-but-ide-reports-the-type-or-namesp

@ALex came to the same conclusion I did, that deleting the .suo files <i>temporarily</i> fixes the issue.

Comment: @simon-co also had the idea of deleting those AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 and AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 folders. I did that…problem still came back a few days later.